# Rails (ActiveRecord) coalesce or how to update only empty values in a table

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, padrino

With Mysql I can use `COALESCE` to update only the values that are emtpy in a table.

How can I do this with Rails (ActiveRecord)?

I don't want to create `if` statements for each column in the table and am guessing there has to be a way to do it if I pass an ActiveRecord hash to the `update_attributes` method.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

It's not so clear what you're asking but if I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :street, :city, :zip
  def update_null_attributes(hash)
    update_attributes(hash.keep_if { |k,v| __send__("#{v}_was").nil? })
  end
end
```

This will take the hash of attributes you want to update and pass only the ones that were originally nil.  It uses [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) for the "#{v}_was" method.

Comment: Whoever down-voted this answer, would you like to share why?  I can't improve the answer if I don't what's wrong with it.

Comment: This was most likely downvoted because it's not atomic. If two resources read the same record at once you'll lose the first write. You would need to lock the record.